# How can text in the options configuration of Docopt be wrapped?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, docstring, docopt

I have a few detailed option specifications in the docstring used for configuration of Docopt. Some of the items are quite lengthy. Is there a way of wrapping the text to make it more legible or to make it fit to a line width more easily?

Let's say the relevant bit of text in the docstring is the following:

```
Usage:
    program [options]

Options:
    -h, --help                      Show this help message.
    -c, --configuration=CONF        Configuration (file) [default: None]
    -f, --files=FILESLIST           Comma-delimited list of input data files [default: 169888_ttH_el.root]
    -v, --variables=VARIABLESLIST   Comma-delimited list of variables to plot [default: trk_pt]
    -t, --tree=TREE                 Tree in input data files [default: mini]
    -u, --username=USERNAME         Username
    -t, --topanalysis=DIRECTORY     Directory of TopRootCore or TopAnalysis [default: /home/user/Dropbox/TopAnalysis]
    -s, --superlongoption=TEST      This is a very long option that requires a bit of text to explain it. [default: 101001011011101010010100110101010]
    --version                       Show the version and exit.
```

Would it be possible wrap the text in a style something like the following?

```
Usage:
    program [options]

Options:
    -h, --help                      Show this help message.
    -c, --configuration=CONF        Configuration (file) [default: None]
    -f, --files=FILESLIST           Comma-delimited list of input data files
                                    [default: 169888_ttH_el.root]
    -v, --variables=VARIABLESLIST   Comma-delimited list of variables to plot
                                    [default: trk_pt]
    -t, --tree=TREE                 Tree in input data files [default: mini]
    -u, --username=USERNAME         Username
    -t, --topanalysis=DIRECTORY     Directory of TopRootCore or TopAnalysis
                                    [default: /home/user/Dropbox/TopAnalysis]
    -s, --superlongoption=TEST      This is a very long option that requires a
                                    bit of text to explain it.
                                    [default: 101001011011101010010100110101010]
    --version                       Show the version and exit.
```

Comment: Click might do what you want.  "The default behavior of Click is to rewrap text based on the width of the terminal "   You can also disable auto behavior w/ '\b' - http://click.pocoo.org/4/documentation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## How is option definition and description defined

The "secrets" are:

- option definition starts on any line, starting with `-` or `--` (blanks ignored).
- option definition and option description must be delimited by at least two spaces.
- option description ends as soon as next option definition is found. Under-indented lines or blank lines do not end the description.
- any [defaults: block] being part of option description is valid and is used.

## How to deal with description formatting

There are few things, which help using longer option descriptions or option definitions.

- Option description may start on any line following option definition.
- Option description may be wrapped.

  - Even under-indented lines are part of the option description.
  - To keep the text legible, keep option description indented to fixed column (e.g. 27 or 29 or other column you find practical). This is recommendation, not a rule)
  - [default: block] works well as long as it is considered part of option description. Even under-indented text works and blank lines are allowed too. Just put it anywhere before you define next option.
- The text `Option:` has no real meaning (regardless often use in tutorials of `docopt`). Options are recognized as any line starting with `-` or `--` (initial blanks are ignored). This allows breaking the options into groups.
- be aware, that option definition and option description must be delimited by at least two spaces.

## How was original code reorganized

Here is example of reorganized **doc** string from your example.

What was done:

- option description text starts at column 27
- where option definition ended in column 25 or later (not allowing 2 spaces before option description text starts), option description text was moved to next line.
- Options organized into logical groups (to show it is possible)
- Option groups got some description.

## Rewritten example

Final code looks as follows:

```
"""
Usage:
    program [options]

General options:
  These things are rather general, so placed in this group of option.

    -h, --help            Show this help message.
    --version             Show the version and exit.
    -c, --configuration=CONF
                          Configuration (file) [default: None]

Directory and path related stuff:
  Whatever relates to file or directory, comes here.

    -f, --files=FILESLIST
                          Comma-delimited list of input data files
                          [default: 169888_ttH_el.root]
    -t, --tree=TREE       Tree in input data files [default: mini]
    -t, --topanalysis=DIRECTORY
                          Directory of TopRootCore or TopAnalysis
                          [default: /home/user/Dropbox/TopAnalysis]
Other things:
  Remaining options live here.

    -v, --variables=VARIABLESLIST
                          Comma-delimited list of variables to plot
                          [default: trk_pt]
    -u, --username=USERNAME
                          Username
    -s, --superlongoption=TEST
                          This is a very long option that requires a bit of text
                          to explain it.
                          [default: 101001011011101010010100110101010]
"""
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from docopt import docopt
    args = docopt(__doc__)
    print args
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed and clear answer. It responds to what I asked and advises a good approach for related concepts. Thanks!